# Cannot deduce the "auto ia2(ia)" while ia is an array

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, clion

I am using `CLion 1.05`,

```
int main() {
    int ia[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto ia2(ia);
    auto ia3(&ia[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, `ia2` and `ia3` point to the same address, and the code works well. However, the `CLion` seems cannot deduce `ia2` correctly, and underlines the `auto ia2(ia)` to be red.

Is it a bug in `CLion` or other issues ?

[image]

Comment: What is "the `Cloin`"?

Comment: spelling mistakes. It is **CLion**.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CLion bug. Works fine in Visual Studio and XCode.

Whether that's good code to write is another question :)